# JavaScript failed to execute "transferControlToOffscreen"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, offscreen-canvas

I am trying to do below code for transferring canvas to worker:

```js
var mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var offscreenCanvas = mycanvas.transferControlToOffscreen(); // Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'transferControlToOffscreen'
// Code to transfer to worker.js
```

```html
<div id="divCanvas" style="width:100%;">
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

But When I do below code it does work:

```js
var mycanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
mycanvas.setAttribute("id", "canvasChart1");
document.getElementById('divCanvas').appendChild(mycanvas);
var offscreenCanvas = mycanvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
```

```html
<div id="divCanvas" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

What is the difference between both the implementation?
Can we avoid creating canvas at the runtime and use existing?

Comment: Can't repro. Do you have any plugins or other scripts in the page that could try to get a context from the canvas before your script runs? Btw, the error message should tell you more about why it couldn't perform the call (*Cannot transfer control from a canvas for more than one time.* or *Cannot transfer control from a canvas that has a rendering context.*)